RANGE vs HASH partitioning for high volume time series data in postgres
I have a large time series data set consisting of ~3 months of records, something like 6-8 billion rows. It's very write heavy compared to reads but the access pattern will be consistently tied to secondary id columns. I'm considering a strategy of combining HASH partitioning (on that secondary id) to spread the write load around, with BRIN indexing on timestamp and secondary_id to make the reads performant, but I'm not sure I really understand the engine enough to be confident in this approach.
Normally I would prefer RANGE partitioning for this type of data (since it is time series and append only) as that would facilitate easy ttl ejection using DROP TABLE, but it seems like this will mean that all writes (and tbqh most reads) will be concentrated only on the most recent partition. If I hash on the secondary id, writes will be spread evenly and individual reads will not cross partition boundaries. Am I missing something? I'm planning on doing some bench marking but it's a bit difficult to be fully confident in the results given the volume of production data.

Will the partitions be on different physical devices?

@LaurenzAlbe not initially, managed rds fwiw

Then you are not spreading the write load by using partitioning. It still all goes to the same device. Partitioning may help if contention on the index is your problem, but only if.

There is a UUID PK on the rows to facilitate future replication, but I don't love that and full replication mode would obviate the need for the index overhead...
I'm going to try with ranges and some other tweaks then, thank you!

With uuid you should get no contention on individual index pages.

Ok, good to know that! I would have thought there would be some not trivial insertion overhead even for uuid because of the backing btree index.
